# python have an a problem with css in static

Tags: css

I made css file but I don't know how to turn it on in web site, and I don't know to which folder i should put my css file. Please help me

```
#video-player{
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: inline-block;
}
img{
    background-color: Aqua;

}
#video-tree{
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
}
video{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
#progress-tree{

    background-color: CadetBlue;
}
#progress{
    height: 5px;
    width; 50%;
    background-color: Black;
}
#button-tree{
    height: 50px;
}
#button-tree > * {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: You include a CSS file in HTML by putting `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css"/>`. You can put the CSS file anywhere you want, provided you include the correct (absolute or relative) path when you link to it. Any basic HTML/CSS tutorial will cover this. And what does the question have to do with Python? Is this in the context of a Python web framework like Flask or Django? If so, you need to give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Include the CSS file in your html. [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) for more info.
Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

The CSS file needs to match the name entered above, in this example "style.css".
It has to be in the same folder aswell. If you want to place it in a new folder, add that path to the href aswell. For example, if you want to add into a "CSS" folder, do the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```